# Trouble Updating to Version 13.10 (from Version 13.04)

Tags: updates, software-center, update-manager

By trying to update to Version 13.10 (German) from Version 13.04 i'd received the following Problem-Message:

```
W:Fehlschlag beim Holen von "http: //de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found"
W:Fehlschlag beim Holen von "http: //de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-backports/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found"
W:Fehlschlag beim Holen von "http: //de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-backports/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found"
W:Fehlschlag beim Holen von "http: //de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found"
E:Einige Indexdateien konnten nicht heruntergeladen werden. Sie wurden ignoriert oder alte an ihrer Stelle benutzt.
```

Update rolls back

Anyone got an solution?

Comment: Have you tried changing servers?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10. The issue seems to be that the "natty-backports" repositories are not working properly. If you disable them the problem gets solved.

To do so, edit the file /etc/apt/sources.list directly.

From a terminal:

sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

then comment out the two lines that contain "natty-backports". Lines 34 and 35, I think.

Save and try running the update again. You may have to do a manual "check for updates".

Hope it works for you!